# can I get windows SDK for xp on visual studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

I want to compile old C++ source code that I got from github and this is old apps which is need windows xp SDK and v141_xp build tools, I've tried to download manually from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8442 but this is not detected on my IDE. As you know old windows SDK as unavailable on visual studio package installer

Comment: not need any old sdk. latest sdk files must be ok too

Comment: MS does not provide a supported configuration but if you know MSBuild you could create one yourself. However if all you want to do is build it would likely be easier to just use the command prompt that was created as part of the SDK install and build from there rather than trying to get VS integration.

Comment: nah man, this source code is need visual studio 2010 cause of build tools and that's IDE is paid...

Comment: "Support for Windows XP development by using the Visual Studio 2017 v141_xp toolset is available as an individual component option in the Visual Studio Installer." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/configuring-programs-for-windows-xp?view=vs-2019